# How do you change font size in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I am trying to change the font size of a label I have in tkinter, but no-matter what I try I don't get the result I am looking for. I have tried `font=("Arial", 20)` and `size=fontsize+2`. But none of them really work well. Does anyone know what I should use?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve] which illustrates what you've tried.

Comment: I did say what I tried

Comment: No, you gave an approximation of what you tried. We don't know if you literally did `font=("Arial", 20)` (eg: creating a local variable named `font`) or `Label(root, font=("Arial", 20))` or `Label(root, size=fontsize+2)` and so on. Actual code is much more useful than a description of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to change the size of font then try

```
label.config(font=("Arial", 20))
```

If you want to change width

```
label.config(width=200)
```